# alias and absolute path in storybook config

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a React/Typescript project with Storybook. Storybook works great, but as soon as I start importing files with aliases, it crashes.

```
    import defaultAvatar from "images/avatar.png" => crash 
    import defaultAvatar from "../../images/avatar.png" => ok
```

my main.js is like this:

```
const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

and this is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types/", "./node_modules/@types/"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["es2020", "es2019", "DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "models/*": ["./src/models/*"],
      "providers/*": ["./src/providers/*"],
      "services/*": ["./src/services/*"],
      "types/*": ["./src/types/*"],
      "helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
      "images/*": ["./src/images/*"],
      "pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"],
      "hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
      "propTypes/*": ["./src/propTypes/*"],
      "fonts/*": ["./src/fonts/*"],
      "config": ["./src/config"],
      "__mocks__/*": ["./__mocks__/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "../*/cypress/**/*"]
}
```

and also webpack config is like:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/'),
      providers: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/providers/'),
      services: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/services/'),
      models: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/models/'),
      types: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/types/'),
      helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/helpers/'),
      images: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/images/'),
      pages: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages/'),
      hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/hooks/'),
      propTypes: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/propTypes/'),
      fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/fonts'),
      config: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/config'),
      __mocks__: path.resolve(__dirname, './__mocks__/'),
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
```

I am on webpack 4.43.0 and storybook 6.1.20, I wonder how can I fix the issue and what is the best solution?

Comment: Instead of paths in tsconfig, try to use `resolve.alias` for these paths in webpack config https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Comment: @rachitiitr actually, I already defined resolve alias. alias in webpack config, I added here

Comment: Most likely you will get the solution at https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3339 as well